# How to forbid object copying in swift3?

Tags: swift3

I want to be sure that every instance of the object is used by reference. Instantiated it could be several times but should not be copied.
F.e. in c++ it is easy to do:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator = (const A&) = delete;
};
```

That is. Of course smbd could try to make some hack  in memory - but it is not useful and not so easy. You should know exactly the memory layout of your object and all fields it encapsulates. I do not want smth special - just equivalent of the code above in swift 3.

Comment: You cannot make sure that. Even if you manage to disable copying to object itself, using pointers, its memory address can be accessed and the contents of it copied. You cannot disallow users of your code from accessing the memory. I guess you are creating a framework and you want to protect some interval variables from being misused. In that case, provide more context and someone might be able to offer you a workaround, but what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: @DávidPásztor your guessing is too complicated. I just want to disable regular copying for the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, [classes are reference types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID89). So they already do what you want: they can be held by reference only. They'll always be on the heap, and assignments will act to assign references, not class contents. So just make sure you declare your object as a `class` rather than a `struct` — unlike C++ the primary difference between the two in Swift is reference type versus value type.

Comment: My question is related to objects in general - not only classes. We should not do that for classes - how to do that for `struct`s?